# Cannot get drag and drop to work onto NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

There is probably a simple mistake that I'm making, but I simply cannot get dropping of files onto an NSCollectionView to work even in the most basic way.

In a test project, I have an NSCollectionView on a window, and the view controller is both its delegate and data source. I want to be able to drag files from the Finder onto this collection view.

From reading the docs, all I should have to do is:

Register for dragged type(s):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"Registering dragged types for collection view: %@", self.collectionView);
    [self.collectionView registerForDraggedTypes:@[NSFilenamesPboardType]];
    [self.collectionView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:YES];
    [self.collectionView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];
}
```

And then implement these two methods:

```
-(NSDragOperation)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo proposedIndex:(NSInteger *)proposedDropIndex dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation {

    NSLog(@"Validate drop: %@", draggingInfo);

    return NSDragOperationMove;
}

-(BOOL)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView acceptDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo index:(NSInteger)index dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation)dropOperation {

    NSLog(@"Accept drop: %@", draggingInfo);

    return YES;
}
```

But none of the two methods is ever called, when I try to drag an item onto the collection view, which makes me think that the `registerForDraggedTypes:` call is not working as expected.

What can be the issue here? What else do I have to look into?

Comment: Duplicate of [Example for Drag and Drop inside NSCollectionView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42329390/4244136)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From OS X 10.11 the `NSCollectionViewDelegate` methods take an index path instead of an index. For instance in

```
-(NSDragOperation)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo proposedIndex:(NSInteger *)proposedDropIndex dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation
```

the `proposedIndex:` parameter is replaced by `proposedIndexPath:`

```
- (NSDragOperation)collectionView:(NSCollectionView *)collectionView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)draggingInfo proposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * __nonnull * __nonnull)proposedDropIndexPath dropOperation:(NSCollectionViewDropOperation *)proposedDropOperation
```

Comment: Thanks. Note: Xcode autocomplete is suggesting the old (wrong) version that will never get called. It's still present in NSCollectionView.h, and anlthough marked as "old", it doesn't mention that it doesn't work any more.

Comment: This is still a problem for macOS 10.14