# NSCollectionViewDelegate methods aren't getting called

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView where I would like to show 6 color wells representing a small color palette. I've set it to have a delegate. I've registered the types that it can drag and drop, but the delegate methods for it aren't getting called.

Here's the class that's both my data source and delegate:

```
class TileView: NSView, NSCollectionViewDataSource, NSCollectionViewDelegate {
    var currentPalette: ColorPalette = .grayscale
    @IBOutlet var colorPalettePanel: NSPanel? = nil
    @IBOutlet var colorCollection: NSCollectionView? = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        colorCollection?.registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.color])
        colorCollection?.setDraggingSourceOperationMask(NSDragOperation.move, forLocal: true)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
        draw(into: context)
    }

    // MARK: - Collection View Data Source Methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let colorIndex = indexPath.last
        let result = ColorCollectionViewItem(nibName: "ColorCollectionViewItem", bundle: Bundle.main, colorIndex: colorIndex!)
        let color = gCustomPalette6 [ colorIndex! ]
        result.colorWell?.color = NSColor(cgColor: color)!
        return result
    }
    
    // MARK: - Collection View Delegate Methods
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, validateDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, proposedIndex proposedDropIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, dropOperation proposedDropOperation: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSCollectionView.DropOperation>) -> NSDragOperation {
        print("dragging Info = \(draggingInfo), proposed drop operation = \(proposedDropOperation)")
        return NSDragOperation.move
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, acceptDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, index: Int, dropOperation: NSCollectionView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
        if dropOperation == .before {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, canDragItemsAt indexes: IndexSet, with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, draggingSession session: NSDraggingSession, willBeginAt screenPoint: NSPoint, forItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        print("dragging session = \(session)")
    }
}
```

I've set the delegate in Interface Builder, but none of the delegate methods are ever called.

My delegate object is also the data source and the data source methods all get called as expected. The data source is also set up in Interface Builder. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Have you selected the collection view and set the data source to it through the interface builder?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above. "The data source is also set up in Interface Builder."

Comment: I cannot give you any advice unless you show the entire class.

Comment: OK, I've added it. Please let me know if there's anything else you need. Thanks!

Comment: You must be kidding.  Why are you using `NSCollectionView` with `NSView`?  `NSCollectionView` is not a subclass of `NSView`.  `NSCollectionViewItem` IS a subclass of `NSView`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Your comment is self-contradictory. Regardless, the data source and delegate for an NSCollectionView can be any class you want. In my case, since this is just a practice project, I just threw them into my view class because it was convenient. That fact is rather irrelevant to my question, though. Do you have an answer for why my delegate methods aren't getting called? I agree that this is not how you'd normally architect a shipping app.

Comment: What you are trying to do is the same as using `UICollectionView` under `UIView` in iOS.  `NSView` is not a view controller.  Neither is `UIView`.  It's the end of the discussion.

Comment: @ElTomato ` NSCollectionView` is a subclass of `NSView`. ` NSCollectionViewItem` is a subclass of `NSViewController`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get drag and drop to work onto NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867465/cannot-get-drag-and-drop-to-work-onto-nscollectionview)

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you! Code completion gets me again.  Thank you for your help. It works perfectly now despite my odd object hierarchy.